# How to use right the dialog command in the sh script?

Tags: linux, shell, dialog, sh

I wrote some script:

```
#!/bin/sh

dialog --menu \
"Please select a partition from the following list to use for your \
root (/) Linux partition." 13 70 3 \
"/dev/hda2" "Linux native 30724312K" "/dev/hda4" "Linux native 506047K"


DISKS='"disk1" "50 Gb" "disk2" "100 Gb"'

dialog --menu \
"Please select a partition from the following list to use for your \
root (/) Linux partition." 13 70 3 \
$DISKS
```

The first call looks good.
[image]

The second call looks bad.
[image]

I need to transmit information about the drives through the variable. Please tell me why the second version of the call does not work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
$ shellcheck myscript

In myscript line 9:
DISKS='"disk1" "50 Gb" "disk2" "100 Gb"'
      ^-- SC2089: Quotes/backslashes will be treated literally. Use an array.


In myscript line 14:
$DISKS
^-- SC2090: Quotes/backslashes in this variable will not be respected.
```

The [detailed error page](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2089) offers an explanation:

---

> Bash does not interpret data as code. Consider almost any other languages, such as Python:

```
print 1+1   # prints 2
a="1+1"
print a     # prints 1+1, not 2
```

> Here, `1+1` is Python syntax for adding numbers. However, passing a literal string containing this expression does not cause Python to interpret it, see the `+` and produce the calculated result.
>
> Similarly, `"My File.txt"` is Bash syntax for a single word with a space in it. However, passing a literal string containing this expression does not cause Bash to interpret it, see the quotes and produce the tokenized result.
>
> The solution is to use an array instead, whenever possible.

---

Ok, let's try that:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISKS=("disk1" "50 Gb" "disk2" "100 Gb")

dialog --menu \
"Please select a partition from the following list to use for your \
root (/) Linux partition." 13 70 3 \
"${DISKS[@]}"
```

This works.

However, this is a bash specific solution. If you want it to work for `sh`, in this case, you can pick a delimiter other than whitespace by setting the Internal Field Separator:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=":" # Split on colons
set -f  # Prevent globbing
DISKS='disk1:50 Gb:disk2:100 Gb'
dialog --menu \
"Please select a partition from the following list to use for your \
root (/) Linux partition." 13 70 3 \
$DISKS
```

This also works as expected. If your script is longer than this, you'd want to set IFS back to its original value.